# Partial Data Being Ingested To Azure Data Explorer From Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer

I currently have an Azure Data Explorer setup to ingest data from Event Hub. For some reason unknown to me, my ingestion table is only seeing about 45% of events. I am testing this by sending 100 events to event hub individually at a time. I know my event hub is receiving these events because I setup a SQL table to also ingest these events, and that table is receiving 100% of them (under a separate consumer group). My assumption is that I have setup my Azure Data Explorer table incorrectly.

I have a very basic object I am sending

```
public class TestDocument
{
     [JsonProperty("DocumentId")]
     public string DocumentId { get; set; }
        
     [JsonProperty("Title")]
     public string Title { get; set; }
 {
```

I have enabled streaming ingestion in Azure

```
Azure Data Explorer > Configurations > Streaming ingestion (ON)
```

I have enabled streaming ingestion in my table

```
.alter table TestTable policy streamingingestion enable
```

My Table mapping is as follows

```
.alter table TestTable ingestion json mapping "TestTable_mapping" '[{"column":"DocumentId","datatype":"string","Path":"$[\'DocumentId\']"},{"column":"Title","datatype":"string","Path":"$[\'Title\']"}]'
```

My data connection settings

```
Consumer group: Its own group    
Event system properties: 0
Table name: TestTable
Data format: JSON
Mapping name: TestTable_mapping
```

Is there something I am missing here? Consistently, out of 100 events sent, I only see about 45-48 get ingested in my table.

EDIT:

Json payload of TestDocument

```
{"DocumentId":"10","Title":"TEST"}
```

Comment: (1) It may help if you could include a sample of the input payload (in JSON format). (2) just a guess: try reconfiguring the data connection with format 'multijson' or 'multilinejson' instead of 'json'. (3) see if there are any ingestion failures when you run `.show ingestion failures`

Comment: @Yoni Thanks for the input. I've tried multijson, and only receive about 8 out of 100 events. Ingestion failures only show errors when I had data connection data format set to multijson or, compression set to GZip.

Comment: It may help if you could include a sample of the input payload (in JSON format).

Comment: It sounds like a competing consumer on your consumer group. I know you've stated it has its own CG but I can't see any other way to explain the behavior. Very easy to test with a new CG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what is happening, I am adding a BOM to my serialized object, and it looks like ADX has issues with it. When I tried serializing my object without a BOM, I was able to see all data flow from event hub to ADX.

Here's a sample of how I am doing it:

```
private static readonly JsonSerializer Serializer;

static SerializationHelper()
{
    Serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(SerializationSettings);
}

public static void Serialize(Stream stream, object toSerialize)
{
    using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, DefaultStreamBufferSize, true);
    using var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter);
    Serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, toSerialize);
}
```

What fixed it:

```
public static void Serialize(Stream stream, object toSerialize)
{
    using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false), DefaultStreamBufferSize, true);
    using var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter);
    Serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, toSerialize);
}
```